# What is the direction of current flowing through the primary coil and secondary coil of a transformer?

Tags: current

I am very much confused about the direction of the induced current in the secondary coil in a transformer. I am sharing a video tutorial. Please help me understand this. [To see the video click here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Tm2c6NJH4Y&t=2192s)

In this video between 36:25 min - 37:28 min they are showing current flowing through a transformer. According to the statements between 32:50 min - 36:24 min, I think the direction of the current flowing through the secondary coil as shown should be in the reverse direction.

I think if the direction of current flow is in--

```
primary coil     -------     secondary coil

  clockwise         ------      anti_clockwise
  anti_clockwise    ------       clockwise
```

but...in the video --

```
primary coil     -------     secondary coil

  clockwise         ------      clockwise
  anti_clockwise    ------      anti_clockwise
```

---

Why?

Comment: ... Lenz's law ...

Comment: I can probably identify with your confusion because even I took time to realise that the clockwise / anticlockwise current direction flow on solenoid faces to determine magnetic poles - would not apply for a coil inducing current on another coil which follow lenz law

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current is flowing the way you think it should be, but the perspective is odd so it looks like the current is flowing the same way in both loops. It's clearer a bit later (few seconds) when they show the transformer core.

The left inductor is wound opposite of the right inductor; the top leg of the left inductor is pictured below the bottom leg of the same inductor, so it looks like it's in line with the bottom leg of the right inductor.

[image: Current Flow]

Comment: great.....i was waiting for this type of answer.....thanks a lot Chuck♦......

Answer (score 0):

If the current in the secondary and the related load current in the primary flowed "the same way", this would instantly increase the flux in the transformer core. That would (due to Faraday's law of induction) significantly increase the transformer secondary output voltage. That would cause more current to flow and more flux and more voltage and lead to virtually instant meltdown.

That doesn't happen of course: load currents flow in opposing directions and this means the core flux remains unchanged and Faraday's law of induction remains valid.

Strictly speaking I shouldn't call it current but ampere turns i.e. the ampere turns in the secondary cancel out the load associated ampere turns in the primary but, for a 1:1 transformer it's easy/lazy to just refer to current.

[image]